# How to kill the parent process and its children on ctrl+C or ctrl+Z

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I have the main process in my program that fork() some children processes and then goes into endless loop (Also, the children processes are endless). Now, I want to kill all processes, close a socket, de-attach shared memory, and clean all similar stuff on terminating the program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I search the internet and I found that I could do that by sending some signals like SIGSTOP and SIGINT, but I don't know how to do it.So, how can I accomplish this in my program?

Comment: ^Z generally does not terminate the program, but just suspend it, so that it can be continued at a later point.

Comment: I think you've roughly got the answer. See the kill(2) man page for the system call to send signals to other processes: http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill

Also, you'll want to read up on signal handlers, the sigaction man page referenced, or I highly recommend using libev, a state machine, to dispatch code when a signal is received. It protects you from mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

From outside the program, you can send any process a signal using the [`kill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command.

By default, kill will send the `SIGTERM` signal, which will terminate a process, and free its allocated resources.  You can use the `ps` command to find the process ids of your program's processes.  Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> will only terminate the parent process.  It will not kill the child processes.  If you just forked, and didn't exec a new program, then all of your child processes will have the same name as the parent, which means you can use the [`killall`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) command to terminate them all in one go.  If you are logged in remotely, then logging out will cause a `SIGHUP` signal to be sent to all of the processes you spawned during the session,  which will terminate them by default.

From inside the program, there is a [`kill()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) function that operates similar to the command.  You will need the process ids still, so it's important that your parent code remembers the child process id returned by fork.

Answer (score 0):

When your process exits brutally, all resources are certainly freed.

However, if you want to control the behaviour (what order, etc, I don't know what) then you should install a signal handler. See `sigaction(2)`.

Comment: Shared memory is one of those exceptions. A segment must be marked for destruction and then when all clients of that segment exit the memory is freed. http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmctl